# Phonegap android textbox duplicate instance

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I bumped into very weird problem.

When I'm focusing (by touch) on textbox in my phonegapp app I see 2 textboxes.

See the attachment:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that the ultimate solution is to hide the "real" textbox which android try input to.. that solved my problem

Comment: Can you advice how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30964) when you use fixed/absolute positioning. Android tries to enhance the text field 'transparently' like predictive input, language selection etc. and with fixed/absolute positioning, it has trouble overlaying it exactly on top. On Kindle Fire, this is even more obvious. Try making your layout flexible/responsive!

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. The problem is the "outline" property of the input field:

```
 input[type="text"]:not(.selectbox), input[type="number"],
 input[type="password"] {
 -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  outline-style: none;
 }
```

**Ref:**https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30964